# Addition of 2 timestamps from 2 different fields SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lets say I have two timestamps from two different fields. How would I sum both the timestamps. In my case the two fields are "expected_start_time" and "expected_runtime". Here is just an example (I dont want to hard code these times I want to use the field names expected_start_time and expected_runtime...these are just example values to show the addition). I want this in an UPDATE statement. Thanks!

Timestamp 1 (expected_start_time) : 2022-07-14 04:00:00 UTC

Timestamp 2 (expected_runtime) : 0000-00-00 00:10:00 UTC

Sum of them I want: 2022-07-14 04:10:00 UTC

Comment: `0000-00-00 00:10:00 UTC` is not valid timestamp. You should rectify your use case!

Comment: How can I add two timestamps then using node js or sql

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, as there are a few ways you could interpret "Addition."

I am going to assume you are asking for a straight addition of the two dates and not some sort of concatenation.

In this case, `DATEPART()` is your friend! [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp)

`DATEPART()` allows you to pick apart a `date` or `datetime` and returns the portion of the date you requested *as an integer*.

For example, if you wrote:

`select datepart(year, '2020-01-31')`

Your result would be **2020**.

Therefore, you could use a variety of `DATEPART()` and `CAST()` functions to get the parts of the dates that you need, and perform your addition.

Example:

```
select cast(datepart(year, '2017-01-01') + datepart(year, '2020-01-01') as nvarchar) + '-' 
+ cast(datepart(month, '2017-01-01') + datepart(month, '2020-01-01') as nvarchar)
+ '-' 
+ cast(datepart(day, '2017-01-01') + datepart(day, '2020-01-01') as nvarchar)
```

This takes my two dates and adds their year, month, and days respectively, casts them from integers back to strings, and concatenates them all into a single string: 4037-2-2.

Of course, you could then cast this whole thing back as a `date` or `datetime` if you wanted, and you could even perform a `DATEADD()` if you wanted.

I hope this points you in the right direction!